# vuex is not updating state in mobile device

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to implement logic when user signin after that get that info and call axios GET to get the data and save in state this is working fine in desktop but, not in mobile.

Comment: Not sure how you think we can help with just this amount of info. More details, some code or any lead is highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to refresh the version of the JS file you have in your mobile browser .. don't thank ..

Comment: How to do that?